# How to create a list of numbers with specific condition

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to create a list of number like yymmddaabbbb

yy:year;
mm:month;
dd:day;
aa:specific numbers like 01, 21 ect;
bbbb: from 0000 to 9999

Is it possible to create a list of number like I stated above?
I am beginner in Excel, but I really need to know how to do it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: I am beginner in excel, but i really need to know how to do it

Comment: Do it by formula. Something like `CONCAT(FORMAT(NOW(), "YYMMDD"), "21", FORMAT(ROW(), "0000"))`...

Comment: @Akina, I tried, but #NAME? appeared. How to fix? Pls help me, thanks

Comment: My formula is approximate.

Comment: @Akina, I tried again, only formula appeared, but the number i required still not appear. Pls help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked how to create a list yymmddaabbbb but did not give further details.

For below, the number of rows = the length of your list.

- Start at row 1
- for each row, enter in the cells the following
- In column A enter the desired yy
- In column B enter the desired mm
- In column C enter the desired dd
- In column D enter the desired aa
- In column E enter the desire bbbb
- In column F enter `=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1,E1)`
- Copy `F1` to `F2` and so on

Tips:

Excel can help you fill cells. Select two or more cells in a column and in lower right is small square, put your mouse over it and it will turn into a plus sign "+", click on it and drag it down.

IF you already have an adjacent column full of data, you can DOUBLE click the square box and Excel will automatically fill in the cells to the bottom of the list.

If your selected cells, that you started with, all have the same number, that number will be filled in. The number will stay the same number

If the cells have 1, 2, and 3, Excel will fill in your bbbb numbers to 1000 automatically. Excel will increase the number by one for each row

Excel will also update the formula above so that the row number will update so that `=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1,E1)` will become `=CONCATENATE(A2,B2,C2,D2,E2)` and so on. (A1 = column-row)

Comment: I need something like combination of numbers. when i tried the concatenate like you suggested, the thing that appeared is A1B1C1D1E1. How to fix it, thanks.

Comment: @nirmala remove the quote marks from the formula. I edited the answer to fix that error.

Comment: is it possible to drag the formula down for ten thousands of time quickly?

Comment: Should be, I just did 5000 in about twenty seconds

Answer (score 0):

Your data will consist of a **prefix** part and an **incrementing** part.

Say we want the prefix part to be:

*2012256677*

In **A1** enter the formula:

```
=ROW()-1
```

Then apply this custom format to **A1**:

*"20122256677"0000*

[image]

Then copy **A1** downward:

[image]